# Regular Expression RE sub()

Tags: python, text

```
import re
text = 'section{First} section{second}'
p = re.compile('section{([^}]*)}')
print 'before substitution: ', text
print 'after substitution: ', p.sub(r'subsection{\1}', text)
```

Results:

```
before substitution:  section{First} section{second}
after substitution:  subsection{First} subsection{second}
```

Why the second section is also substituted accordingly? How can I just replace the first section with subsection? And how can I replace both {First} and {Second} with {First} in the substituted string?

Comment: [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) has an optional `count` argument to limit the number of replacements.

Comment: To change both texts to `subsection{First}` replace `r"\w+"` with `"subsection{First}"`.